# is it possible to log (but allow request to be fulfilled) invalid referrers using nginx?

Tags: logging, nginx, referrer

when using nginx as a simple webserver (no reverse proxy magic, not even cgi, etc...) is it possible to set a list of VALID referrers and do something like :

```
if ( referrer not in list of VALID referrers ) {
    log this referrer
}
```

is something of this sort possible using a standard nginx source OR any additional modules/extensions?

as i understand this could possibly be slightly involved, no need for a full conf write up... pointing me at the correct conf directives will suffice :)

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
http {
  map $http_referrer $log_ref {
   default               0;

   http://referrer1/path 1;
   ~^http://referrer2/   1;
  }

  server {

    location / {
      if ($log_ref) {
        access_log ....
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Nginx version 0.9.6+ supports regular expressions in `map`. Marker `~` serves to denote them.

Comment: this looks like what i am looking for, but a further question about the above: i see the list of valid referrers as protocol://host/path... would it be possible to expand this into a protocol://host/* style list? what we want to allow is a small list of hosts to be allowed, and all others (after we log them, and take a look at whats actually going on since we as of right now do not even know) denied. so listing http://valid_referer/page1, page2, page3 etc is not realistic. let me know what you think.

Comment: booyah! have been wanting to do this for about 6 months. thank you kindly alex.